# How to select two or more columns of a table and send through GET / POST?

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button, html-table

I have a simple HTML table generated using Mysql and PHP.

I would like to choose one row of my table, and send **two or more** contents through GET or POST to another page, using the easy way as possible.

Today, I can send only **one** parameter using "radio" button like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="table.php">
<table>
<?php
$query="SELECT * from prices ORDER BY region limit 10";
$result=mysql_query($query,$connection);
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="radio" name="region"  value="<?php echo $linha['region'] ?>" /></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['region']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['platform']; ?></td>  
     <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>                                      
    </tr>
</tbody>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>       
</form>
```

So, if I click in "Submit" button I got:

```
table.php?region=ap-northeast-1
```

How can I get, for example:

```
tabela.php?region=ap-northeast-1&type=c1.medium
```

=== Edit:

That's how my table looks like:

```
type    region  platform    price $/h
m3.xlarge   ap-northeast-1  windows 0.980
hs1.8xlarge ap-northeast-1  rhel    5.810
hi1.4xlarge ap-northeast-1  rhel    3.960
m1.medium   ap-northeast-1  windows 0.230
cg1.4xlarge ap-northeast-1  rhel    4.450
cc2.8xlarge ap-northeast-1  rhel    3.100
c1.xlarge   ap-northeast-1  rhel    0.855
c1.medium   ap-northeast-1  rhel    0.254
m2.4xlarge  ap-northeast-1  rhel    2.135
m2.2xlarge  ap-northeast-1  rhel    1.079
```

And I would like to be able to sent the values "type" **AND** "platform" to another page :)

Comment: Make the type a form field as well

Comment: you could create a hidden input and every time the radio is selected set the hidden value using javascript

Comment: Use `checkbox` instead of `radio`?

Comment: @JohnConde can you give some example please?

Comment: @putvande  'checkbox' allow me to send more than one line, I would like to send two data in the **same** line :)

Comment: @chepe263 I need to use JavaScript to to this? Can you please give me some example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three ideas:

You could use jQuery (javascript) for this

```
<form method="get" action="table.php">
<input type="hidden" name="platform" id="platform" />
<table>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>region</td>
    <td>platform</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>$/h</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" class="regionSelectRadio" name="region"  value="m3.xlarge" /></td>
    <td>m3.xlarge</td>
    <td>ap-northeast-1</td>
    <td>windows</td>
    <td>0.980</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.regionSelectRadio').click(function(){
            jQuery('#platform').attr('value', jQuery(this).parent().children().eq(3).html() );
        });
    });
</script>
```

You could use a separate form for every record:

```
<form method="get" action="table.php">

<table>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>region</td>
    <td>platform</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>$/h</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Select"/> <input type="hidden" name="region"  value="m3.xlarge" />
    <input type="hidden" name="platform" value="windows" />
    </td>
    <td>m3.xlarge</td>
    <td>ap-northeast-1</td>
    <td>windows</td>
    <td>0.980</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<form method="get" action="table.php">

<table>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>region</td>
    <td>platform</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>$/h</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Select"/> <input type="hidden" name="region"  value="m3.xlarge" />
    <input type="hidden" name="platform" value="windows" />
    </td>
    <td>m3.small</td>
    <td>ap-southeast-1</td>
    <td>unix</td>
    <td>0.980</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You can also put the two values in the same option input and then split in php:

```
<form method="get" action="table.php">

<table>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>region</td>
    <td>platform</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>$/h</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" class="regionSelectRadio" name="region"  value="m3.xlarge;windows" />
    </td>
    <td>m3.xlarge</td>
    <td>ap-northeast-1</td>
    <td>windows</td>
    <td>0.980</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>region</td>
    <td>platform</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>$/h</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" class="regionSelectRadio" name="region"  value="m3.small;unix" />
    </td>
    <td>m3.small</td>
    <td>ap-southeast-1</td>
    <td>unix</td>
    <td>0.980</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
$values = explode(';',$_REQUEST['region'])
?>
```

Comment: I'm also interested in your jQuery example, but here, when I click this is what I got: `table.php?platform=&region=m3.xlarge` do you know what is missing here? :) Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

you can use hidden field for type

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks Bhumi, but I'm probably doing this wrong. Look what I got:

`table.php?type=m3.xlarge&region=ap-northeast-1&type=hs1.8xlarge&type=hi1.4xlarge‌​&type=m1.medium&type=cg1.4xlarge&type=cc2.8xlarge&type=c1.xlarge&type=c1.medium&t‌​ype=m2.4xlarge&type=m2.2xlarge`

Should I put this inside the loop? Thanks

Comment: what you have done? have you create multiple hidden fields? pl provide code here

Comment: I just did:

`code
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="region"  value="<?php echo $row['region'] ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="type1" value="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>" /></td>
<td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['region']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['platform']; ?></td>  
<td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td> 
</tr>
</tbody>`

Thank you

Comment: if you are using multiple fields then you need to pass different name and if your fields are in loop , you can use name="type[]" . if still have confusion,pl let me know.

Comment: Hey @Bhumi Shah I'm still confused... Sorry, I'm sysadmin and not developer, hehehehe... I just updated my question with the table, can you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have code or hidden field in loop? if yes then pl take as array like  <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use input type `hidden` to do this:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
```

If your storing multiple values,then use array to do so.Here is the code:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
```

In **Table.php** you can retrieve those values using `foreach` like this:

```
<?php
   foreach($_GET['type'] as types)
    {
      echo types;
    }
?>
```

To  get values of radio button, simply use `$_GET['region']` in table.php.

Comment: Thanks Joke, but I'm probably doing this wrong. Look what I got:

`table.php?type=m3.xlarge&region=ap-northeast-1&type=hs1.8xlarge&type=hi1.4xlarge‌​&type=m1.medium&type=cg1.4xlarge&type=cc2.8xlarge&type=c1.xlarge&type=c1.medium&t‌​ype=m2.4xlarge&type=m2.2xlarge`

What I'm doing wrong? :( Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Joke_Sense10 I feel that we are getting closer now! Ok, you teach how to retrieve a array of information from a radio button, but how can I put the variables that I want there?

I've tried: 
`name="type[]", value="m3.xlarge,ap-northeast-1"
name="type[]", value="m3.xlarge" , value="ap-northeast-1"
name="type[]", value="m3.xlarge" value="ap-northeast-1"`

But I can' yet :) Thanks!!

Comment: You dont have to store different values every time,as it is already in a  `while` loop.So the `type[]` will contain all your values.In table.php you just have to use `foreach` loop to retrieve those like I already did in my answer.